# How can I customize the validation error response in hapi.js?

Tags: node.js, hapi.js

When using the [config.validate option on a route](http://hapijs.com/tutorials/validation) and a request fails due to validation, hapi returns an error like:

```
{
    "statusCode": 400,
    "error": "Bad Request",
    "message": "child \"weight\" fails because [\"weight\" is required]",
    "validation": {
        "source": "payload",
        "keys": [
            "weight"
        ]
    }
}
```

Is there a way to send a different formatted validation error?

Comment: Could you post the config.validate object that you are using in the route spec?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

There are two ways to customize the output:

1. Using the [`failAction`](https://github.com/hapijs/hapi/blob/master/API.md#route-options) attribute in `config.validate`:

   ```
   config: {
       validate: {
           params: {
               name: Joi.string().min(3).max(10)
           },
           failAction: function (request, reply, source, error) {

               error.output.payload.message = 'custom';
               return reply(error).code(400);
           }
       }
   }
   ```
2. Using the [`onPreResponse`](https://github.com/hapijs/hapi/blob/master/API.md#request-lifecycle) extension point:

   ```
   server.ext('onPreResponse', function (request, reply) {

       var response = request.response;
       if (response.isBoom && response.data.name === 'ValidationError') {
           response.output.payload.message = 'custom';
       }

       return reply.continue();
   });
   ```

See the [API documentation](http://hapijs.com/api#error-transformation) for more details.

Comment: In the first example, I had to leave out the `.code(400)` part because when one provides the error object to the reply function, the `code()` function isn't present in the object returned by `reply()`. The response code is set to 400 automatically by the error object passed into `reply()`.